# How to select earliest date with condition

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql, min

Is it possible to select the earliest Open_Date from the below table on the condition that Sub_ID's Status is either Open or Complete?

| Order_ID | Sub_ID | Open_Date | Close_Date | Status | Status_Update_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5555 | 001 | 2018-07-16 | NULL | Open | 2018-07-16 |
| 5555 | 001 | 2018-07-16 | 2022-03-01 | Cancelled | 2022-03-01 |
| 5555 | 002 | 2022-03-25 | NULL | Open | 2022-03-25 |
| 5555 | 002 | 2022-03-25 | 2022-03-28 | Complete | 2022-03-28 |
| 5555 | 003 | 2022-05-01 | NULL | Open | 2022-05-01 |

The result from the above example should be 2022-03-25 (Sub_ID 002), because Sub_ID 001 ended up being Cancelled, although 001 does have an Open_Date.

Running a simple MIN query would just give me the result of 2018-07-16 and I really don't know how to code it to omit 2018-07-16 and return 2022-03-25.

```
SELECT 
    MIN (Open_Date) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Order_ID, Sub_ID, Open_Date, Close_Date, Status, Status_Update_Date 
     FROM 
         Orders 
     WHERE 
         Order_ID = 5555) AS X
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please try to provide a insert statement and create statement for ease thanks.

Anyway [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hHLSl5hc) is the answer.

```
select min(open_date)
from orders o
where o.sub_id not in (
    select sub_id
    from orders o2 
    where o2.sub_id = o.sub_id and o2.status = 'cancelled'
)
and o.order_id = '5555'
```

**Explanation:** The subquery will select the list of all the sub_id's that are cancelled and will exclude from the list so you will have a list of all sub_id's which don't have cancelled on them.
And then from the list you can select the min data with order_id = '5555'

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first open date for order 5555, where the order was colpleted you can use

```
 SELECT TOP 1
     Order_ID, Sub_ID, Open_Date, Close_Date, Status, Status_Update_Date 
 FROM 
     Orders 
 WHERE 
     Order_ID = 5555 AND Status = Complete
 ORDER BY Open_Date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(Open_Date) AS Earliest_Open_Date
FROM Orders
WHERE Sub_ID IN (
    SELECT Sub_ID
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Status IN ('Open', 'Complete')
    GROUP BY Sub_ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) = 2
);
```

**Explanation:**

The inner subquery selects Sub_ID values that have both 'Open' and 'Complete' statuses. The HAVING clause with COUNT(DISTINCT Status) = 2 ensures that both statuses are present for a Sub_ID.

The outer query then calculates the minimum Open_Date among the Sub_ID values selected by the inner subquery.